# FCM - onTokenRefresh is never called on multi-flavored android app

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a multi-flavored android app. The package name is the same for both flavors (com.mycompany.base). In the app level gradle file, the two flavors have their own appplication IDs (com.mycompany.firstflavor, and  com.mycompany.secondflavor).

In the past, for google play services like maps, I used both application IDs and get the google-services.json file that includes information for both flavors. I only need to copy this json file into my app and everything worked fine.

Lately I created a FCM project in order to implement push notification, and added each flavor as an app using their application IDs as before. At first, I only included one coppy of the json file in the suggested location in the app. When I ran the app on one flavor, it said Firebase was initialized successfully. However, the onTokenRefresh method was never called. I searched on the internet, and there were some related topics, but none of the solutions worked in my case. When I ran the app on another flavor, the app kept crashing with the error message: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzb(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzab; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzab' appears in /data/app/com.suran.dwmobile-2/base.apk:classes2.dex). The issue happened on both real devices and simulators. I then copied the json file into two locations as suggested by some I read online. The same json file now appears in two places, under each flavo, e.g., app/src/firstflavor, and app/src/secondflavor. But this didn't help at all, and I still had the same issue. And this is only the debug mode.

When I ran the app with build variant set to release, with both flavors I got the error message: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzv$zza$zza.class. I found some answers to similar issues, but none of them can solve my problem.

Here is part of my manifest file which may be useful for debugging:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:amazon="http://schemas.amazon.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.mycompany.base"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21"
    />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission   android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="archos.permission.FULLSCREEN.FULL" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="false"/>

    <application
    android:name=".application.BaseApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/CompanyTheme"
    >
        <service android:name=".FBInstanceService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="come.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name=".FBMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is my app level gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    signingConfigs {
        firstflavorRelease {
            storeFile file("XXXXXX.jks");
            storePassword("XXXXXXX");
            keyAlias "XXXXXXX";
            keyPassword "XXXXXXX";
        }

        secondflavorRelease {
            storeFile file("XXXXXXX.jks");
            storePassword("XXXXXXXX");
            keyAlias "XXXXXXXXX";
            keyPassword "XXXXXXXX";
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }

    }

    productFlavors {
        firstflavor {
            applicationId = "com.mycompany.firstflavor"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.firstflavorRelease
            versionCode 1000
            versionName "1.9.2"
        }

        secondflavor {
            applicationId = "com.mycompany.secondflavor"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.secondflavorRelease
            versionCode 1000
            versionName "1.2.2"
        }
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':myappCore')
    compile files('libs/amazonmaps-1.0.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/zbar.jar')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:2.2.0'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.1"
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.1'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent:1.6.1'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.6.1'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.1'
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.2.2"


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And here is my project level gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Update your build dependencies to use version 9.2.1 of the `play-services-*` libraries to make them consistent with the `firebase-*` libraries.

Comment: @BobSnyder I followed your suggestion to change the versions of play-services-maps, play-services-gcm, and play-services-auth to 9.2.1 to match that of fire-basemessaging. Because I used the deprecated MapView.getMap, I then have to change that to use MapFragmentFragment. After the changes, the errors I had before were gone, which is very good news. Thank you very much for that. But onTokenRefresh is still not called. If I call FirebaseInstanceId.getInstanc().getToken() somewhere else in one of my activities, I can get the token as before. But I don't think that solved the problem.

Comment: I still need the firebase messaging services. Since the firebase instance service's method is not called, I don't think the method in the messaging service will be called, which includes a lot of my handling of the message, and is important for the push notification implementation. I still think that there is something wrong with the way I put the google-services.json file or used the applicationIDs rather than the package name? But I also added app using the packagename in my Firebase console. So there are actually three apps for my firebase project.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days struggling with the issue, I finally found where the problem was. In my manifest file, I incorrectly set the android name for the service action to be: come.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT rather than com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT.

Comment: But I do have another question. As I said in my original post, I used each flavor's applicationID to create the applications in my firebase project. However, my android project's package name is different from these application IDs.

Comment: When I process firebase messages in onMessageReceived(), I need to build a stack of activities where my app can go to the top one. When the user click back, it should follow the stack to get the next from the top and so on. The problem is that in onMessageRecived(), it appends the applicationID to the activity name when I use stackBuilder.addParentStack(activity.class), which is incorrect. If using the fully qualified name is unavoidable, how can I replace the applicationID with the real package name? Thanks